# Page order Changed and now getContext is Null

Tags: asp.net, canvas, razor

I changed my applications so a different page would load when ran but now I receive the error

> Unable to get property 'getContext' of undefined or null reference

It's not causing any problems yet but I'm hoping to fix it before it does.

Looking online this usually happens when a `<canvas>` tag comes before a `<script>` tag but I cannot find where this is occurring.

```
@using Application.Models;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@{
    User user = ViewBag.User;
}

@if (ViewBag.Loader)
{
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
            <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
            <title>@ViewBag.Title - Application Title</title>
            <script id="userData" class="userData" type="application/json" data-accurate-up-to="@user.AccurateUpTo">
                @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }))
            </script>

            @Styles.Render("~/Styles/lib")
            @Styles.Render("~/Styles/css")   
            @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/lib")

        </head>
        <body>
        <!-- Navbar -->
            <div id="nav">
                <div id="smallLogoHolder">
                    <img id="smallLogo" src="~/Images/sidewaysLogo.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="navContents">
                    <div id="logoHolder">
                        <img id="logo" src="~/Images/logo.png">
                        <div id="slogan">Application Name<div id="dayOTheYear"></div></div>
                        <script>
                            setInterval(function () {
                                $("#dayOTheYear").text("(Day: " + moment().dayOfYear() + ")");
                            }, 1000 * 10);
                            $("#dayOTheYear").text("(Day: " + moment().dayOfYear() + ")");
                        </script>
                    </div>

                    <ul id="menu">
                        <a href="~/Page 1"><li class="navItem @if (ViewBag.Title == "Page 1") { @("activeNavItem"); }">Page 1</li></a>
                        <a href="~/Page 2"><li class="navItem @if (ViewBag.Title == "Page 2") { @("activeNavItem"); }">Page 2</li></a>
                        <a href="~/Page 3"><li class="navItem @if (ViewBag.Title == "Page 3") { @("activeNavItem") ; }">Page 3</li></a>
                        <a href="~/Page 4"><li class="navItem @if (ViewBag.Title == "Page 4") { @("activeNavItem") ; }">Page 4</li></a>
                    </ul>

                    <div id="userSection">
                        <div id="loginSection">
                            <div id="loginSectionPic" style="background-image: url(@("path" + User.Identity.Name.Replace("DOMAIN","").Replace("/","").Replace("\\","")))"></div>

                            <div id="loginSectionContent">
                                <span id="user">@User.Identity.Name.Replace(@"DOMAIN\", "")</span>
                                <span id="userType">
                                    @if (user.SecurityGroup.Name != "N/A")
                                    {
                                        @("(" + user.SecurityGroup.Name + ")")
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        @("(No Role)")
                                    }
                                </span>

                            <div><span id="switchUserButton">Switch User</span> | <span id="logoutButton">Logout</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>       

        <div class="dialog notificationDialog">
            <h2 class="dialogHeader">My Title</h2>
            <div class="notificationMeta">Sent by <span class="notificationSubmittedBy"></span><br /><span class="notificationSubmittedTime"></span></div>
            <div class="notificationText">

            </div>
            <input type="button" class="markRead" value="Mark As Read" />
            <input type="button" class="closeNotification" value="Close" />
        </div>   

        @RenderBody()  

        <div id="content">
            <span id="loadingMessage">Loading...</span> <img id="dataLoadingGif" src="~/Images/loader.gif" />

            <script>
                $(window).load(function () {
                    $.get("@Request.Url.ToString()?loader=0", function (markup) {
                        $("#loadingMessage").text("Rendering...");
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $("#content").html(markup);
                        }, 200);

                    }).fail(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#loadingMessage").html("<span style='color:red'>Failed</span><br/><br/>");
                        $("#dataLoadingGif").remove();

                        $("#content").append('<iframe id="yellowScreenOfDeathHolder" style="display:block; width:100%; height: 1000px;"></iframe>');

                        $("#yellowScreenOfDeathHolder").contents().find("html").html(response.responseText);
                    })
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
}
else
{
<div id="title">
    @ViewBag.Title

    @if (ViewBag.Title == "Page 2" || ViewBag.Title == "Page 3")
    {
        <span class="areaTitle"> - All Areas</span>
    }
    else if(ViewBag.Title == "Page 1" || ViewBag.Title == "Page 4")
    {
        if (((User)ViewBag.User).Area != null)
        {
            <span class="areaTitle"> - @(((User)ViewBag.User).Area.Name)</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span class="areaTitle"> - All Areas</span>
        }    
    }
</div>
@RenderBody()

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app")
```

}

This is my `Layout.cshtml` and nothing was changed here, all I did was change some information in my `RouteConfig.cs` to go to a different page.  The reason I linked `Layout.cshtml` is because when the program is ran it gets through loading `Layout.cshtml` and then tells me `.getContext` is null within the jquery

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Page 2", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

All that changed here was `Page 2` used to be `Page 1`, could the `<canvas>` elements on `Page 1` be causing the problems?

**Update:**

After further investigation it returns the error on the `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app")` line so I'm wondering if this script should be called elsewhere.  Where would be a better place to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution to my problem.  Since page 1 requires the `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app")` line I moved it from the bottom of `Layout.cshtml` to `Page 1.cshtml` since `Page 1.cshtml` isn't the first to load anymore.

I'm currently checking to make sure this doesn't cause errors anywhere else, once I've done that I'll mark this as the answer.